# Possibility of using angular 2+ for writing Qlik custom extension

Tags: angular, qlikview, qliksense

I am using qliksense for one of my data visualization project. I was wondering if it is possible to develop a **Custom Qlik extension** using **angular 2+**. Hours of searching online have not resulted in finding any tutorial or article regarding the same. All the articles show examples of using it using angularjs 1.x or js. So my question is

- Is it possible to develop Qlik custom extension using angular2+
- If point one is yes, how this is achieved.

A code example of the same would be of great help. Thanks in advance :)